# Reset billing address to default address

Tags: checkout, orders, event-observer

I'm trying to (re)set the billing address to the customers default billing address after receiving an order (this is for B2B clients which are not allowed to change their billing address). To do this, I have the following code set in a 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action' event listener. (Limited to customers of a specific customer group)

```
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($order->getCustomerId());
$order->setBillingAddress($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress());
$order->save();
```

But upon ordering this results in a TypeError

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\Order::setBillingAddress() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface or null, instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Interceptor given
```

Is it possible to change the address from a `Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Interceptor` to `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface` so this will be properly saved/updated?

Or is there another way I can ensure the orders come in with the default billing address set on the customer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to be to get and set the values individually:

```
// Load customers default address data
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($order->getCustomerId()); 
$default = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();

// Grab the order billing address in a variable for ease-of-use
$billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

// Set the address details with the get-data
$billing->setStreet($default->getStreet());
$billing->setCity($default->getCity());
$billing->setPostcode($default->getPostcode());
$billing->setCountry($default->getCountry());
$billing->setCompany($default->getCompany());
$billing->setTelephone($default->getTelephone());
$billing->setFirstname($default->getFirstname());
$billing->setMiddlename($default->getMiddlename());
$billing->setLastname($default->getLastname());

// And make sure to save/store the data
$order->save();
```